# ICS Wrong Time Zone Appearing In Google Calendar

Tags: time, calendar, google-calendar-api, icalendar, vcalendar

I am having a weird issue with ics calenders. I am creating a calendar with the following information:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:www.bingewave.com
X-WR-TIMEZONE:America/New_york
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:America/New_york
X-LIC-LOCATION:America/New_york
END:VTIMEZONE
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:61bb267c4074e
DTSTART;TZID=America/New_york:20211216T180000
SEQUENCE:0
TRANSP:OPAQUE
DTEND;TZID=America/New_york:20211216T210000
```

The time zone set to `America/New_york` and the time set to 180000, which is 6:00 PM. But I am getting this in my Google Calender:

[image]

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I try to import the file that you posted via `Settings>Import&Export`, and I'm been unable to do it succesfully, I guess that's not the complete file... Have you tried creating an event on the desired date and export it to compare the results? Also, what is the method used to add the `.ics` to the calendar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is case sensitivity. New_york is not recognized, while New_York with a capital Y works. Apparently, Google Calendar is strict on upper and lowercase.